# /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' -- while trying to start the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I end up with this error:

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require':  cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require
>       `from /vagrant/config/boot.rb:6:in`
>       `from bin/rails:3:in`require_relative
>       `from bin/rails:3:in``

I am using a vagrant environment and this is the flow of executing the commands

```
$ vagrant up
$ vagrant ssh
$ cd /vagrant/
$ bundle
$ rake db:create
$ rake db:migrate
```

Then for the tests:

```
$ rspec spec
```

And for running it:

```
$ rails s
```

Comment: what is it failing to `require`? That is not the full error. Are you certain that your vagrant box has the correct dependencies installed?